# Weave RememberMe service with OpenID Connection

Tags: spring, spring-security, jhipster

Can't find the way how to implement `RememberMe` service in OpenID. Have a [class](http://pastebin.com/Mex42PKG) that extends `AbstractRememberMeServices` and it works with simple form login. Have next logs after login:

```
2015-12-17 07:29:15.086 DEBUG 260 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]         p.s.s.CustomPersistentRememberMeServices : Did not send remember-me cookie (principal did not set parameter 'remember-me')
2015-12-17 07:29:15.086 DEBUG 260 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] p.s.s.CustomPersistentRememberMeServices : Remember-me login not requested.
```

Login works through /openid?openid_identifier=IDENTIFIER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add setAlwaysRemember(true); to your AbstractRememberMeServices implementation's constructor.